# String letters are being sent line by line (Set Text Activity)

Tags: c#, settext, uipath

I am new to uipath, I was developing an application to send a text to a text editor. In c# using selenium I was able to send the string successfully using the below code,

```
        string Line = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.txt");

        //the text in the file is
        //{"ifscCode":{"S":"one"},"bankName":{"S":"two"}}

        var textelemetn = Selenium.Selenium.driver.FindElementByClassName("ace_text-input");
        textelemetn.SendKeys(Line);
```

but when I am trying to send the text using the "Set Text" Activity in UIPath to the control it is being sent one by one and without special character like double quotes [image]

I can use type into option to send the text but that is taking around 12-15 seconds for one line and there are nearly 3000 lines that are to be added where I cannot take time.

Not sure how can I proceed. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered using the "Write Text File" activity and then opening it in your text editor?

Answer (score 0):

To save string values in file, you can use "Write Text File" activity and you don't need to open an text editor to do it.
Just type file path in "FileName" field and your string variable in "Text".
If you stiil need do open modified file, use "Start Process" activity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).